# webpacker won't compile when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpacker

I've recently tried integrating react into my preexisting rails app by using the webpacker gem. When I try to push to heroku, I see the an error message like

```
remote:        [1/5] Validating package.json...
remote:        [2/5] Resolving packages...
remote:        [3/5] Fetching packages...
remote:        [4/5] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [5/5] Building fresh packages...
remote:        success Saved lockfile.
remote:        Done in 0.09s.
remote:        Compiling…
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        error Command "webpack" not found.
remote:        
remote:        yarn run v1.12.3
remote:        info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for 
documentation about this command.
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to spitball-production.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/spitball-production.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

My package.json looks like

```
{
   "name": "Spitball",
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
    },
   "engines": {
   "yarn": ">=0.25.2"
   }
}
```

I've tried the solutions involving adding buildpacks and installing yarn and webpacker and so far nothing has helped. I'm expecting everything to push through no problem as all I've done is add the webpacker gem.

Comment: Did you upgrade to rails 5? If yes, you might find the answer here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/522

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running

`$ rails assets:precompile`

in your terminal prior to pushing to Github then Heroku?
You have to compile all of your assets files prior to being built by Heroku.

Comment: When I do so, it triggers a 'yarn install' command which fails because of an 'EACCES: permission denied' error. Are you familiar with this problem, I believe this might be the crux of the issue.

Comment: Do, you run use RVM or RBENV? I know that it means that you don’t have write access where it is trying to install yarn. You need to either use chmod to give full access to that path. I believe I had this problem not long ago and I cleared it up by removing and reinstalling my RBENV

Comment: I believe I use RVM. I tried running chmod 777 on the project path for my rails project, but got the message 'No such file or directory'

Comment: I reinstalled RVM and still have the error. It is a problem of write access, do you know what the proper command is to fix this?

Comment: When you install rails does it require a sudo to gem install?